# can't display shopping cart values using jquery labels and sum variables

Tags: jquery, input, label, keyup

Is simple php shopping cart. Looking to display the total value (label cost * quantity entered) when user add an amount in inputs text and display the total value for each product. The cost of each product are inside label for each product on different divs. At the end, display the total value (sum total) for each product on the cart.

```
<form>
    <div><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="combine"></div>
    <div>$<label id="cost">2.50</label></div>
    <div>$<label id="total">0.00</label></div>

    <div><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="combine"></div>
    <div>$<label id="cost">5.00</label></div>
    <div>$<label id="total">0.00</label></div>

    <div>Grand Total <label id='gtotal'>$0.00</div>
</form>
```

Need help for this incomplete jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var form = $('.combine');
    var vals = form.map(function () {
            var value = $.trim(this.value)
            return value ? value : undefined;

        }).get();

        $(".combine").keyup(function(){
            var quantity = $(this).val();
            var cost = ? ; 

            $('#total').text((quantity * cost ));
            $('#gtotal').text( sum of all #total );
        });

} );
```

The result I need, when user add Qty amount on textfield, jquery display Total and Grand Total:

- Product 1 - Qty. 5 Cost: $2.50 Total: 12.50
- Product 2 - Qty. 3 Cost: $5.00 Total: 15.00

Grand Total: $27.50

Working link with one product only: http://jsfiddle.net/0L4j8qnj/

---

Any suggestion to change any code to simple way to do it, would be appreciated too.Thanks.

Comment: You meant "utterly broken" when you wrote "incomplete"?

Comment: ? mark on var cost mean. I don't know how to get var cost value to multiply them by input quantity, display them for each product on label #total and display sum of all on #gtotal label at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Found a similar working code: http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/gsjJv/